# why do some "if" tests not work in my cron scripts

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have been "toying" around with this for some time now, for most issues i just worked around, but now i need this solved.

Why do basically all my cron jobs dont work with "If tests"

lets take this one

```
if [ "$line" == "downloads.php" ]
```

works absolutely fine when i run it in the shell, when i start it as cron job it just never works. The workaround

```
if echo "$line" | grep -q "downloads.php"
```

works both ways. Why is that? For the first one the [ ] basically stand for "test", and the second one well, its just a grep. But why are the "tests" not working in my cron jobs? (with or without redirection to >null)

i currently need this one in a cron job, and now i don't really know how to work around, or basically i just finally want to understand how to solve this, what I am doing wrong.

```
while [[ "${ofile: -1}" != "_" ]]
```

this one just produces an error "87: Bad substitution", do until first character is "_"

i managed to overcome all issues with cron, from full paths, to environment, this one is still a puzzle for me. any help is appreciated.

Comment: The grep will also match if `downloads.php` is a part of the line, not the whole line.

Comment: Where does `$line` come from? Note that the working directory for a `cron` job is likely different from the one you are in when you test it outside of `cron`. So depending upon how `$line` is generated, this could be the difference.

Comment: Looks like you are executing the code in cron via `/bin/sh`, but manually as `/bin/bash`.

Comment: yes, the first example should work if it is just part of the line    
  
  
$line can be either
- for line in $(cat FILENAME) do ... done
- while not EOF do .... done <FILENAME

i prefer the "for" construct. i'd love to format this comment, but two space just dont make a line break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are running the script with bash, while cron is running it under some other shell; thus, all of the bash extensions you're using are failing. Make sure the shebang on your script (i.e. the first line) requests bash (`#!/bin/bash`), and that the cron entry runs it directly rather than specifying a shell (e.g. `0 0 * * * /path/to/script` NOT `0 0 * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script`).

EDIT: there are several different ways of controlling which shell will be used to interpret a script, with a definite precedence order:

1. If you run the script with an explicit shell (e.g. `/bin/sh /path/to/script`), the shell you told to run it will be used, and any shebang will be ignored.
2. If you run the script directly (e.g. `/path/to/script` or `./script`, or place it in your PATH and run it as `script`), the system will use the shebang to determine which shell (or other interpreter) to run it with.
3. If you run it directly and there's no shebang, the program you're running it from (e.g. bash, sh, or crond) *might* choose to do something else. In this situation, bash will run the script with bash. I'm not sure what crond will do, and it might even depend on which version it is.

In general, using a proper shebang and running the script directly is the best way to go; the script should "know" what the proper interpreter is, and that should be respected. For example, if you write a script in portable shell code (with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang), and then later need to use some bash-only features, you can simply change the shebang and not have to track down all the places it's run from.

Specifying the shell explicitly should be reserved for cases where the shebang is wrong or missing (in which case the better solution is to fix the script), or you don't have execute permission (again, fix the script). The third option is an unreliable fallback, and should be avoided whenever possible.

P.s. If I'm reading your last comment (above) correctly, you want to test whether $line *contains* "downloads.php", not whether it equals that; but the `[ x == y]` comparison tests for equality, not containment. To test for containment, use the bash-only `[[ string == pattern ]]` form:

```
if [[ "$line" == *"downloads.php"* ]]
```

Comment: yes, that was it. tested it direct after jordanm suggested it. i just could never figure out why to add "/bin/bash" at the beginning, script were running with or without it fine. would have saved me a lot of troubles finding this out 1 month ago. thanks to all of you for the prompt help